# JSON only parse new items from last call

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have been trying to get this piece of code to return only newly added items from the json url, i been thining maybe to add push the ID into an array and then run a compare but all attempts didnt seem to work out.

ultimately would like to have the code run every x mins and output only the new posts added since call.

any help here would be really appriciated

```
var request = require("request")

var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"

request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function callback(error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var info = body;

        for(let counter of info) {
        var id = counter.id;    
        var title = counter.title;
        var body = counter.body;
        console.log(id,title,body)
        }

    }   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use settimout to call the API in every `x` mins

```
setTimeout(function(){ //yourcode
 }, 3000);
```

Declare a global variable above and push new values

```
var val

val = val.push(newVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to run every x seconds.

To identify new post mark newPost flag to true and push to your global array, and after showing the new post mark the flag back to false.

```
var request = require("request")

var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
var posts = []

setInterval(function () {
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function callback(error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            var info = body;

            for(let counter of info) {
            var id = counter.id;    
            var title = counter.title;
            var body = counter.body;

            posts.push({
            id: id,
            title: title,
            body: body,
            newPost: true
            })

        }
    }
  })
}, 3000);
```